# "Some same thing/person"

Tags: articles

I wonder if it is correct to say "some same thing/person", in order to mean some thing/person same as the one just mentioned earlier? If not, what is the correct way to express the meaning?

My concern is that: is "same" always preceded with "the"?

Comment: An example would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My concern is that: is "same" always preceded with "the"?

Yes, "same" is always preceded with "the". This is not always the case in speech e.g. "Same thing here". But this is actually a case of elision of the word "the".

In writing, however, "the" always precedes "same" i.e. "it is same thing" is incorrect, and should be "It is the same thing."

You could however, still use "some", as in:

> Some of the same thing/ person

But "the" is still needed to precede "same"

Comment: In which sentence would you use "some of the same (person)"?

Comment: The criminals in this case were some of the same persons involved in the previous one.

Comment: You used "some of the same persons," not "some of the same person." Isn't _persons_ in official and formal contexts?

Answer (score 2):

"Some same person" is not correct. You should say "the same person," or "some of the same people."

> I saw a person talking with Michael. The same person was waiting for him some days before.
>   It's no surprise that some of the same people who are willing to pray for rain don't trust reverse osmosis.