# Can you use "same" without "the"?

Tags: grammar

I've been racking my brain trying to think of a grammatically correct sentence that uses *same* without *the* earlier in the same (see!) phrase.

> It is **the same**
>
> It is **the** very **same**
>
> I have 10 things all **the same**
>
> I have 10 of **the same** things
>
> **The same** boy as last time did it again
>
> The boy did **the same** thing as last time

I am discounting ***same-day** dry cleaning* and any similar phrases that might crop up because using a hyphen is acceptable which suggests it's an atomic phrase and it sounds awkward if inverted:

> They have a same-day dry cleaning service.
>
> Their dry cleaning service is same-day. - Sounds odd but might be acceptable in some situations
>
> Their dry cleaning service is done on the same day. - Sounds better

So I don't think it's possible when *same* is used by itself. Can someone either explain why *same* must always have *the* before it or provide a grammatically correct counter-example?

Comment: "That very same person was here yesterday"; "Those exact same people were here yesterday";

Comment: This question may already have an answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195122/is-it-grammatical-to-use-same-or-the-same-in-substitution-for-an-objective-p and here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31700/some-same-thing-person and here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94793/should-i-refer-to-north-koreans-and-south-koreans-same-people-or-the-same-peo?s=28|0.7563

Comment: @centaurus No, it's not a dupe at all. Those questions ask about "some same person" or about using "same" on its own. All of the answers on those pages are in any case, incorrect

Comment: @Araucaria That's why I used "may".

Comment: Cited question, sank same.

Comment: @Centaurus Yes, just wanted to point out for potential close-voters :) Not a criticism!

Comment: Just FTR, note that in current English it's now very common to use "Same.", alone,  as a whole sentence.  It means basically "I agree with you and have had the identical experiences, and agree with your outcomes and decisions."

Comment: HI Araucaria.  I apologise, I have never seen that (very strange) usage before.   Allow me to revert the edit  Cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, I haven't that much either. Had to look it up to check my teacher buddies here (who were chipping in) weren't wrong! :-) Feel free to edit any of my posts if you reckon there's any typos etc. I might get back to you to check sometimes though!

Comment: "Meet the new boss, same as the old boss." (Although that is perhaps best considered to be a case of the elision of one or more words, including "the".)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The word *same* is usually used with the definite article. However, it can be used with any central determiner which marks the noun phrase as definite:

- these same ideas
- those very same people
- my same friend
- whose same idea
- Ben's same problems

There are also some stock phrases which don't use the definite article. For example the two word reply:

- Same difference.

There are also a few examples of *same* being used with an indefinite article in published books. Here's a quote from a philosophy book:

- Striking as well is that a same idea is several times repeated, but each time the wording shows up to be somewhat different.

We can even find examples of *same* with the negative determiner *no*:

- The chairman and vice-chairman would serve a term of 1 year, with no renewal of term for the chairman (either as chairman or vice-chairman) and the further stipulation that **no same** person may serve as the vice-chairman for a consecutive period of more than two years.

Notice that using "*same*" with these determiners *and* the definite article leads to ungrammatical results:

- the these same ideas
- those the very same people
- my the same friend
- the whose same idea
- Ben's the same problems
- a the same idea
- the no same person

This is because English does not allow two so-called central determiners for the same noun.

Comment: In what context can "no same person" be used? When I read that my mind automatically leaps to it being a typo of "no sane person."

Comment: @KyleStrand "The chairman and vice-chairman would serve a term of 1 year, with no renewal of term for the chairman (either as chairman or vice-chairman) and the further stipulation that **no same** person may serve as the vice-chairman for a consecutive period of more than two years" was the last one I found ... Don't *think* that's a typo, but could be wrong :) Would be quite amusing as "no sane person".

Comment: @KyleStrand What do you reckon?

Comment: That's certainly not a typo, though I would have phrased it as "stipulation that the same person may not," rather than "no same person may." So I guess I'd say I don't really consider that "good English", but it's an attestation, at least.

Comment: @KyleStrand That phrasing sounds completely fine to me, but I agree that your rephrasing is also correct. Consider these rephrasing with synonyms: "...the further stipulation that no identical person may serve as the vice-chairman..." or "...the further stipulation that no duplicate person may serve as the vice-chairman...".

Comment: @DCShannon To me there's no clear meaning for "identical person" (identical to what?), much less "duplicate person" (a clone, maybe?).

Comment: @KyleStrand Really? Identical to the previous person. The same person. A duplicate of the previous person. The same person.

Comment: @DCShannon In the sentence, though, there is no "previous person." It's clear enough what the intended meaning is, but it takes some logical gymnastics and is fairly awkward. (Of course that's subjective, but it's my take.)

Comment: I think your first paragraph answers the question. Examples 3-5 sound odd to me. I'd say _identical_ instead. I think I unconsciously but deliberately avoid those constructions, e.g. _the same friend of mine_. _same difference_ is just shorthand for _It's the same difference_. Pity you didn't say which philosophy book! The business example sounds like legalese, is that counted as English? :-P So, it sounds like the literal answer to my question as worded is "Yes" but to the idea behind the question (the spirit of the question) it's "No": _same_ must be preceded by a definite determiner.

Comment: I guess "self-same" is different. Nonetheless it's worth mentioning in the list of examples. Self and same sound a bit redundant when mashed together, but in some examples the combo provides a flavorful multiplier. "That self-same knife slid between the killer's ribs two years later."

Answer (score 8):

*Same* is occasionally used in a technical sense to mean "the aforementioned person/thing." For example:

> We are responsible for the house and any costs of same.

In most typical occasions, however, that would not be considered proper syntax.

Comment: But even in that case, omitting *the* is a shorthand. It would normally be included.

Comment: Well, it would sometimes be included. Nobody's counting, and this is business/legal language, which is weird to start with. In any event, _same_ is itself a shortening (or if you prefer, an equative pronoun) for _the same `Description` as `Definite NP`_; -- here, _and we are responsible for any costs of the same house that is referred to in the preceding clause_.  I.e, it represents a complete equative construction, whose parts are understood in context, the same way _we are responsible_ is understood.

Comment: Why not 'any costs of the same house'?

Comment: "We are responsible for the house and any costs of the same house" sounds unnecessarily clunky. As John Lawler clarified, this phrasing is legal language. In normal conversation it would probably be "We are responsible for the house and any of its costs."

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

> Two students who give the exact **same** answers on essay questions are probably cheating.  Therefore, I will automatically penalize **same** answers by ten points.