# Using word same without a definite article in technical documentation

Tags: definite-articles

Is the following phrase correct (in whatever sense):

> Geometries passed to this function must have same length

the phrase is used in technical documentation so it would be especially useful to get comments from people who come from a technical background

The following question gives details about the usage of word same with a definite article:

[Can you use "same" without "the"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235076/can-you-use-same-without-the)

however there is a statement "The word same is usually used with the definite article. However, it can be used with any central determiner which marks the noun phrase as definite."

Comment: It reads fine to me, yes it is shorthand but I read it as having an implicit 'the'. If you wished to avoid the issue, swap out 'same' for 'identical'. But I would be happy enough reading that as a functions comment

Comment: I'm glad you found that other question. It really is a perfect dupe. We'll close this question as a duplicate of that one. That said, I understand that you're having trouble applying the advice in the top answer there to your particular sentence here, especially with the comment the leeway permitted by using a "*central determiner*". So the short answer in your case is **yes, you must use *the same length***, including the article *the*, in your particular sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the translation @DanBron, I skimmed the answer and it went over my head, your's is more accessible I feel. Also I was wrong, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @nickson104 If we permit shorthand, slang, and colloquial speech, then the question "*is this correct?*" becomes meaningless; vacuous. Any native speaker reading that sentence would pick up on the absence of *the*; it would stand out. Some would let it pass, most wouldn't, but *everyone* would notice it. If he changed *same* to *identical*, he'd have to change *length* to *lengths*, plural, because now he's talking about two things, instead of one, canonical, normative, *unique* thing. And that's the point: that's why he must use the definite article. *The* same length.

Comment: Nicely put @DanBron, it is a good point that this site is a paragon for what is 'right' and we should not encourage shorthand answers but the ideal. As you alluded to, not all users are native English speakers, and so may not realise some points. Also good spot on the plurals, I didn't think that one through fully. I shall strive for better in future

Comment: Answered at [ELL SE: Does the adjective same always have the definite article the](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/does-the-adjective-same-always-have-the-definite-article-the).