# How do I state the sameness of some number of objects?

Tags: grammatical-number, comparisons

How do you say something is identical and having a quantity greater than two using “(the) same”?

Which is right among below? If there’s no right form, please let me know the right form to describe what I’m trying to say.

Plus, if I have to add “the” somewhere in the phrase, where should it be?

> a. two same pencils
>   b. same two pencils
>   c. the same two pencils
>   d. the two same pencils

Answer (score 1):

In English, it is convention to use "the same two pencils".

*Same* is virtually always used with a determiner. [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235076/can-you-use-same-without-the) is an interesting question about that. Also, [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order) about adjective order should help illuminate why we normally would say "the same two" rather than "two the same" *although* it is also not uncommon to use "two of the same pencils".

Comment: It needs to be noted that "the same two pencils" would generally be taken to mean the two pencils identified are the exact same ones that were previously identified, not simply similar ones.  Not simply both Sanford #2 pencils as before, but the ones carrying your teeth marks from when you last used them.  However, if one was a Sanford #2 and the other a Faber-Castell #2 then the same expression might be taken to mean two pencils of those brands and types, not necessarily the exact same pencils.

Comment: On the other hand, if you previously had two Sanford #2 pencils and you simply wanted another two of the same type, that's when you'd say "two of the same pencils".

Comment: (And, of course, you could substitute another number -- three, five, three hundred and forty-seven -- for "two".)